# DIV heights across multiple divs same height using only css

Tags: html, css

Is there a way with only css to make the height of the div across multiple divs the same height?

The html looks like:

```
<div class="main_wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="meta"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="meta"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the div.wrapper and the div.content to be the same height across the divs. The div.content height is variable in height and I would like the css to pick up the height of the tallest div.content and apply it to all the other div.content divs.  I have added an image to illustrate what I mean.

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: It does not answer the question. The main question is; how do I make sure that the div.content divs are exactly the same height. The link you posted only ensures that the outer div is the same height.

Comment: If the height of the `.meta` elements is always the same - then make the `.wrapper` a flex element, too, and apply `flex-grow:1` to `.content`.

Comment: .meta is flexible in height as well

Comment: Then you will probably have to go with grid instead of flexbox.

Comment: *I would like the css to pick up the height of the tallest div.content* , this is a javascript job , not CSS . If div.content where siblings there could be possibilities, but it is not the case here. We have grid (or flex) but not subgrids yet ;) You may clarify your question with a real example, or explain about that span and size it can have too (your screen shows div.content taking the lowest height but wrapper taking the highest height !?

Answer (score -3):

```
.main_wrapper{
      display:flex;
    }
```